# Restore lost PHPUnit logging functionality

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

1. I'm using `--testdox-xml` in PHPUnit 9.6.10 to generate an XML of the test results for analysis
2. However, that is now gone, together with `--printer` in PHPUnit 10.2.6
3. The analysis I'm doing is to check for the 5 different levels of problem:

   - skipped
   - incomplete
   - failed
   - exception
   - risk
4. My alternative is to rewrite my analyser, at the risk of that format also being removed. I haven't dug into them deeply yet, but the remaining formats don't seem to differentiate into these 5 levels
5. It just seems odd that `--testdox-html` and `--testdox-text` is still around, but XML is not.
6. Is there a quick way to bring back the testdox XML?

Comment: junit.xml never was an option? and for 10, see [Extending the Test Runner](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.2/extending-phpunit.html#extending-the-test-runner) for the new event system. Perhaps its easy to recreate testdox-xml with it, especially as older sources are available. And as the other html and txt are around, they should have been ported to the new event system ... have you taken a look?

Comment: I made some checks, junit and teamcity both don't differentiate into the 5 levels. They seem to treat skipped and incomplete as the same. The only one that doesn't is the new `--log-events-text`. After some thoughts, I will parse this new option. It's a shame that PHPUnit makes such fundamental breaks.

Comment: If you want to fall back to un/semi-structured text, your choice ;) - the alternative are event objects you only need to subscribe to. they should have the properties you're looking for. or best of both worlds: reading the change documentation the implementation of --log-events-text should contain the event subscribing already, you only need to write XML instead of that text (so a little bit more work, but I'd guess less work then parsing). In the end you'd perhaps do both so you can test each against the other.

Comment: Yea I know, but it is part of a production CI/CD and I need to support for PHPUnit 9 and 10 together, understanding extending the test runner will probably take up as much, if not more effort. I looked through `--log-events-verbose-text` and I think I can robustly parse it. My analyser is fairly simple actually, I just need to know the highest severity to have a gauge of how badly broken things are. In time to come, perhaps I might switch to extending.

Comment: Yes, go with the text parser first, from process model this is more straight forward and it will give you results faster. Create the testdox XML as the intermediate?! It's perhaps I also wonder why the XML logger went off, if the other reporters are still there. So this could be a sign that the new event system doesn't have all capabilities yet. Better safe then sorry and check if you can obtain the infos from that --log-events-verbose-text reporting. It's perhaps I'm curious^^